how to add apk compiller in android project
I wanna to make game engine for android (visual novel core).
Created this code to compile to dex, etc file and zip into apk. Using this code I have some troubles. Here's code
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.tools.r8.D8;
import com.android.tools.r8.D8Command;
import com.android.tools.r8.OutputMode;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class TestCompiler {

    private Context context;

    public TestCompiler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean compileApk() {
        try {
            File projectDir = createProjectStructure();
            if (projectDir == null) {
                return false;
            }

            boolean success = compileToDex(projectDir);
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }

            success = packIntoApk(projectDir);
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }

            File apkFile = new File(projectDir, "app.apk");
            if (apkFile.exists()) {
                File outputApk = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "output.apk");
                try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(apkFile);
                     OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputApk)) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, "APK compiled successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to find APK file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to compile APK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private File createProjectStructure() throws IOException {
        File projectDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "MyApp");
        if (projectDir.exists()) {
            deleteRecursive(projectDir);
        }

        if (!projectDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }

        File appDir = new File(projectDir, "app");
        if (!appDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }

        File srcDir = new File(appDir, "src/main/java/com/example/myapp");
        if (!srcDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }

        File resDir = new File(appDir, "src/main/res");
        if (!resDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }

        File manifestFile = new File(appDir, "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml");
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(manifestFile)) {
            writer.write("<manifest xmlns:android=\"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android\"\n" +
                    "    package=\"com.example.myapp\">\n" +
                    "    <application\n" +
                    "        android:allowBackup=\"true\"\n" +
                    "        android:label=\"MyApp\"\n" +
                    "        android:supportsRtl=\"true\"\n" +
                    "        android:theme=\"@android:style/Theme.Material.Light\">\n" +
                    "        <activity android:name=\".MainActivity\">\n" +
                    "            <intent-filter>\n" +
                    "                <action android:name=\"android.intent.action.MAIN\" />\n" +
                    "                <category android:name=\"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER\" />\n" +
                    "            </intent-filter>\n" +
                    "        </activity>\n" +
                    "    </application>\n" +
                    "</manifest>");
        }

        File mainActivityFile = new File(srcDir, "MainActivity.java");
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(mainActivityFile)) {
            writer.write("package com.example.myapp;\n\n" +
                    "import android.app.Activity;\n" +
                    "import android.os.Bundle;\n" +
                    "import android.widget.TextView;\n\n" +
                    "public class MainActivity extends Activity {\n" +
                    "    @Override\n" +
                    "    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {\n" +
                    "        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);\n" +
                    "        TextView textView = new TextView(this);\n" +
                    "        textView.setText(\"Hello, World!\");\n" +
                    "        setContentView(textView);\n" +
                    "    }\n" +
                    "}");
        }

        File valuesDir = new File(resDir, "values");
        if (!valuesDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }

        File stringsFile = new File(valuesDir, "strings.xml");
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(stringsFile)) {
            writer.write("<resources>\n" +
                    "    <string name=\"app_name\">MyApp</string>\n" +
                    "</resources>");
        }

        return projectDir;
    }

    private void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
        if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
                deleteRecursive(child);
            }
        }
        fileOrDirectory.delete();
    }

    private boolean compileToDex(File projectDir) {
        try {
            File classesOutputDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "classes");
            if (classesOutputDir.exists()) {
                deleteRecursive(classesOutputDir);
            }
            classesOutputDir.mkdirs();

            File srcDir = new File(projectDir, "app/src/main/java");
            List<File> sourceFiles = getJavaFiles(srcDir);
            List<String> sourceFilePaths = new ArrayList<>();
            for (File file : sourceFiles) {
                sourceFilePaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
            List<String> compileOptions = new ArrayList<>();
            compileOptions.add("-d");
            compileOptions.add(classesOutputDir.getAbsolutePath());
            compileOptions.addAll(sourceFilePaths);

            int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, compileOptions.toArray(new String[0]));
            if (compilationResult != 0) {
                return false;
            }

            File dexOutputDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "dex");
            if (dexOutputDir.exists()) {
                deleteRecursive(dexOutputDir);
            }
            dexOutputDir.mkdirs();

            File dexFile = new File(dexOutputDir, "classes.dex");

            D8.run(D8Command.builder()
                    .addProgramFiles(Paths.get(classesOutputDir.getAbsolutePath()))
                    .setOutput(Paths.get(dexFile.getAbsolutePath()), OutputMode.DexFilePerClassFile)
                    .build());

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private List<File> getJavaFiles(File dir) {
        List<File> javaFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    javaFiles.addAll(getJavaFiles(file));
                } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".java")) {
                    javaFiles.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
        return javaFiles;
    }

    private boolean packIntoApk(File projectDir) {
        try {
            File dexFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "dex/classes.dex");
            if (!dexFile.exists()) {
                return false;
            }

            File apkFile = new File(projectDir, "app.apk");
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(apkFile);
                 ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)) {

                ZipEntry manifestEntry = new ZipEntry("AndroidManifest.xml");
                zos.putNextEntry(manifestEntry);
                try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(projectDir, "app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"))) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                }
                zos.closeEntry();

                ZipEntry dexEntry = new ZipEntry("classes.dex");
                zos.putNextEntry(dexEntry);
                try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(dexFile)) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                }
                zos.closeEntry();
            }

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

I use custom libs:
implementation('com.zeoflow:jx:1.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'jakarta.activation', module: 'jakarta.activation-api'
    }
    implementation('com.android.tools.build:builder:8.4.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.sun.activation', module: 'javax.activation'
    }

Maybe you know some examples how to create a apk file in anroid os, cuz unless we have root access - i see a lot of errors like: access denied or permission is denied?

Related: How to make an Android app without using Android Studio? and understand that out-of-the-box Android is not fully POSIX compliant so you can examine how it can be done in open source Termux and/or AndroidIDE. Note resources are just references, I have not personally attempted to build APK on Android, YMMV.
